# How to remove the stage controls in javafx without removing the borders for resizing?

Tags: javafx

Hi there is there a way to remove the controls and the decoration of a stage, without removing the borders of the stage?

I know the line : `initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);` but that removes everything from the stage.